# Is there a way to share variables between events in SmartBear Events?

Tags: groovy

I need to set a value in the request header for all requests made to a Restful service based on a value returned in the headers of the initial request using Event Filters in SmartBear Groovy scripts. i.e My initial Restful request returns a 'ConnectionId' in the headers which I need to supply with all subsequent requests from the same client process. In the 'afterStep' event I check if this is the initial request and then call code of the form

```
@Field String ConnectionId = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepAt(0).httpRequest.response.responseHeaders["ConnectionID"]  
   log.info "Connection Id is " + ConnectionId
```

This all works an I can see in the log that it has captured the response header value. In the 'filterRequest' event I need to set the header property 'ConnectionId' to the value returned by the initial request. The filterRequest event has code of the form

```
   headers = request.getRequestHeaders()

  // Add a header to the request
  StringToStringMap headermap = new StringToStringMap(headers)
  
  if (headers.containsKeyIgnoreCase("ConnectionID") ){
      headermap.replace("ConnectionID", ConnectionId)
  } else {
    headermap.put("ConnectionID", ConnectionId)
  }
```

However this does not set the header to the correct value. Any advice on what I doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b434VR_1p6U which explains a solution.